# My Windows 7 is getting the "An error occurred. Press control+alt+del" message on boot

Tags: boot, windows-7

So I upgraded my ubuntu to 12.10 but the Windows 7 problem seems to have happened not after doing the upgrade but later. I am not sure. Ubuntu is running fine, but how can I recover my Windows7? I tried running BootRepair in Ubuntu but it keeps scanning system endlessly... If I recover Windows with the Windows DVD I assume I will lose the GRUB menu and then not possible to start Ubuntu. How do i then proceed to recover the GRUB? Can I recover using the Ubuntu DVD?

Comment: You have to run boot-repair from a live CD/DVD/USB. You can do it again (run boot-repair from a Live DVD) after recovering Windows with Windows DVD.

Comment: So basically use both windows and ubunto dvds to recover is that it?

Comment: @Maxrunner That would probably the best course of action, indeed. First Windows, then Ubuntu. Ubuntu should usually, when booted from a live CD , have no problems accessing the installed version for the repair.

Comment: Forgot to ask, but i've seen some procedures for windows recovery that use the command prompt instead of the menu options is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix Windows via a Windows disk this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get direct access to Windows. (if this fails, you may need to reinstall Windows)
2. then recover the GRUB menu via [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Did this, but after trying to use the liveCD 12.10 installing the boot-repair kept scanning the system forever. I used the livecd 12.04 and after that the windows went back to the previous state. heres the url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1324741/

Comment: Going to recover windows again. It seems boot repair under 12.10 keeps scanning the disk endlessly.

Comment: No solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: You may need a separate /boot partition. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

Comment: Hi there! Need to see this.
regards,